# Reading bits in a memory

Tags: c++

If I have a pointer to the start of a memory region, and I need to read the value packed in bits 30, 31, and 32 of that region, how can I read that value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [bit masks](http://www.somacon.com/p125.php).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how big a byte is in your machine.  The answer will vary depending on if you're zero- or one-indexing for those numbers.  The following function returns 0 if the bit is 0 and non-zero if it is 1.

```
int getBit(char *buffer, int which)
{
   int byte = which / CHAR_BIT;
   int bit = which % CHAR_BIT;

   return buffer[byte] & (1 << bit);
}
```

If your compiler can't optimize well enough to turn the division and mod operations into bit operations, you could do it explicitly, but I prefer this code for clarity.

(Edited to fix a bug and change to CHAR_BIT, which is a great idea.)

Comment: Shouldn't this be: `return buffer[byte] & (1 << bit);`? It feels like you're allowing too many bits to go through if (for example) bit == 3.

Comment: @platinum yup.  Typing too fast.  Fixing now.

Comment: It might be better as `return (buffer[byte] >> bit) & 1;`, to return 1 if the bit is set.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably [generalize this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461482/reading-bits-in-a-memory/3461505#3461505) to something like this:

```
template <typename T>
bool get_bit(const T& pX, size_t pBit)
{
    if (pBit > sizeof(pX) * CHAR_BIT)
        throw std::invalid_argument("bit does not exist");

    size_t byteOffset = pBit / CHAR_BIT;
    size_t bitOffset = pBit % CHAR_BIT;

    char byte = (&reinterpret_cast<const char&>(pX))[byteOffset];
    unsigned mask = 1U << bitOffset;

    return (byte & mask) == 1;
}
```

Bit easier to use:

```
int i = 12345;
bool abit = get_bit(i, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

On a 32-bit system, you can simply shift pointer right 29.  If you need the bit values in place, and by 0xE0000000.